# Installing React Native Fabric Digits on Android

Tags: android, react-native, twitter-digits

I'm trying to install [react-native-fabric-digits](https://github.com/JeanLebrument/react-native-fabric-digits). The documentation says this:

> In MainActivity.java
>
> import com.proxima.RCTDigits.DigitsPackage;         <--- ADD THIS
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
>   return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
>     new MainReactPackage(),
>     new DigitsPackage()                         <--- ADD THIS
>   );
> }
> ```

but my MainActivity.java (using react native v0.40) looks like this:

```
package com.my101;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.proxima.RCTDigits.DigitsPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "My101";
    }
}
```

So... what exactly do I add where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the new way is to add it to `MainApplication.java`

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
   return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new DigitsPackage() 
    );
}
```